# Java 8 Streams: Map with values from sub field

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create a `Map<String, List<Moo>> fooMoos;`

from the following class structure:

```
class Foo {
    String id;
    Bar bar;
}

class Bar {
    List<Moo> moos;
}

List<Foo> foos;
```

If moos would be a field of Foo directly, I would do

```
Map<String, List<Moo>> fooMoos = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Foo::getMoos));
```

But how do you do that with subFields? Is there something like Foo::getBar::getMoos?

I have the feeling I need a flatMap here, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: `Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, foo -> foo.bar.moos)`

Comment: I totally forgot, that you can use lambdas there, too. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be a common pattern, to forget about lambdas or trying to use method references at all costs…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function references are useful, but they dont support chaining. You'll need to use a lambda like

```
foo -> foo.bar.moos
```

or

```
foo -> foo.getBar().getMoos()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's far simpler to use a short lambda. But if you really want to stick to method references, it can be done by chaining the functions. For example, using `Function.andThen`:

```
Map<String, List<Moo>> fooMoos = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId,
        ((Function<Foo,Bar>)Foo::getBar).andThen(Bar::getMoos)));
```

Alternatively, using `Function.compose`:

```
Map<String, List<Moo>> fooMoos = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId,
        ((Function<Bar,List<Moo>>)Bar::getMoos).compose(Foo::getBar)));
```

Similar to the above, in [Guava](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#compose-com.google.common.base.Function-com.google.common.base.Function-), there is a static method `Functions.compose`, which would allow you to use generic type inference to avoid explicit casts:

```
Map<String, List<Moo>> fooMoos = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId,
        Functions.compose(Bar::getMoos, Foo::getBar)));
```

Comment: Nice. Too bad, that there can be only one accepted answer :-(